Python for loop numpy vectorization
Do you have any suggestions how I can speed up the "f_img_update" function in the code below? I tried adding numba @jit decorator, but without luck. I guess that numpy vectorization might work, but I am not enough educated to make it work on my own :/
Code:
import numpy as np
import time
import random
from random import randrange


dimensions = (100, 50)  # [m]
resolution = 5  # [cm] 1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100
pix_res = int(100 / resolution)

height = dimensions[0] * pix_res
width = dimensions[1] * pix_res
img_size = (height, width)

# Make "RGBA" image
img = np.zeros((*img_size, 4), np.uint16)

# DATA PREPARATION
xmin = 1700000
ymin = 1400000
zmin = 100

xmax = xmin + dimensions[0]
ymax = ymin + dimensions[1]
zmax = 150

data = []
for i in range(100000):
    xyzi = [random.uniform(xmin, xmax), random.uniform(ymin, ymax), random.uniform(zmin, zmax), randrange(255)]
    data.append(xyzi)

# IMAGE UPDATE
def f_img_update(f_img, f_xmin, f_ymin, f_data, f_pix_per_1m):  # IMAGE UPDATE
    for f_xyzi in f_data:
        f_x_img, f_y_img = f_xyzi[0:2]
        f_x_img = int((f_x_img - f_xmin) * 100 / f_pix_per_1m)
        f_y_img = int((f_y_img - f_ymin) * 100 / f_pix_per_1m)
        f_img[f_x_img][f_y_img] = f_xyzi
    return f_img


t1 = time.time()
img = f_img_update(img, xmin, ymin, data, pix_res)
t2 = time.time()
print("image update time: ", t2 - t1)


If you just put @jit on top of f_img_update, with this code, you'd be timing the compilation time. That might have thrown things off.

@jit does not even work. It throws "TypeError: cannot reflect element of reflected container: reflected list(reflected list(float64)<iv=None>)<iv=None>"

The easiest way is to convert the data from standard python list to np.array, then use @njit decorator:
import random
import time
from random import randrange

import numpy as np
from numba import njit

dimensions = (100, 50)  # [m]
resolution = 5  # [cm] 1,2,4,5,10,20,25,50,100
pix_res = int(100 / resolution)

height = dimensions[0] * pix_res
width = dimensions[1] * pix_res
img_size = (height, width)

# Make "RGBA" image
img = np.zeros((*img_size, 4), np.uint16)

# DATA PREPARATION
xmin = 1700000
ymin = 1400000
zmin = 100

xmax = xmin + dimensions[0]
ymax = ymin + dimensions[1]
zmax = 150

data = []
for i in range(100_000):
    xyzi = [
        random.uniform(xmin, xmax),
        random.uniform(ymin, ymax),
        random.uniform(zmin, zmax),
        randrange(255),
    ]
    data.append(xyzi)

data = np.array(data)


# IMAGE UPDATE
def f_img_update(f_img, f_xmin, f_ymin, f_data, f_pix_per_1m):  # IMAGE UPDATE
    for f_xyzi in f_data:
        f_x_img = f_xyzi[0]
        f_y_img = f_xyzi[1]
        f_x_img = int((f_x_img - f_xmin) * 100 / f_pix_per_1m)
        f_y_img = int((f_y_img - f_ymin) * 100 / f_pix_per_1m)
        f_img[f_x_img, f_y_img] = f_xyzi
    return f_img


@njit
def f_img_update_numba(f_img, f_xmin, f_ymin, f_data, f_pix_per_1m):  # IMAGE UPDATE
    for f_xyzi in f_data:
        f_x_img = f_xyzi[0]
        f_y_img = f_xyzi[1]
        f_x_img = int((f_x_img - f_xmin) * 100 / f_pix_per_1m)
        f_y_img = int((f_y_img - f_ymin) * 100 / f_pix_per_1m)
        f_img[f_x_img, f_y_img] = f_xyzi
    return f_img


# compile it first
assert np.allclose(
    f_img_update(img, xmin, ymin, data, pix_res),
    f_img_update_numba(img, xmin, ymin, data, pix_res),
)

img_copy = img.copy()
t1 = time.time()
_ = f_img_update(img_copy, xmin, ymin, data, pix_res)
t2 = time.time()
print("image update normal: ", t2 - t1)

img_copy = img.copy()
t1 = time.time()
_ = f_img_update_numba(img_copy, xmin, ymin, data, pix_res)
t2 = time.time()
print("image update time numba: ", t2 - t1)

Prints on my AMD 5700x:
image update normal:  0.07558226585388184
image update time numba:  0.001255035400390625


I have slower AMD Ryzen 5 4600H and the Numba gives me even bigger difference! Thank you!
Results:
(my for loop) image update time:  0.11602473258972168
image update normal:  0.14102983474731445
image update time numba:  0.0030028820037841797

Can you explain to me what is the "assert np.allclose" and how to compile only numba function?

@dany This is only for testing the outputs from numba function and normal function are the same (np.allclose). Running this test for first time also compiles the numba function, so the timing is correct (without compiling step)

I get it. The first run of the function is slow, but the next ones are fast. Is there some way to run/compile it before I really need to run the function?

@dany Yes, you can specify signature explicitely, e.g. @njit("uint16[:, :, :](uint16[:, :, :], float64, float64, float64[:, :], float64)")

It helps, the first run is much faster, but still next runs are even faster :D
I changed dimensions to (1000, 1000) to get more differential results. First run drops from 0.501 to 0.065. Next runs takes between 0.003 and 0.004 s.

@dany You could use @njit(cache=True) to store the compilation result. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/developer/caching.html Please also be aware that the signature for C-contiguous arrays would be @njit("uint16[:, :, ::1](uint16[:, :, ::1], float64, float64, float64[:, ::1], float64)") instead of @njit("uint16[:, :, :](uint16[:, :, :], float64, float64, float64[:, :], float64)")., which is more general but could lead to slower performance.
